# When I turn on html5Mode refresh doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following problem. I'm using AngularJS and angular-route. When I turn on html5Mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

for pretty URL's and if I refresh page I have "Page Not Found" error.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Page title <small>© 2014</small></h1>
    </div>

    <a href="/">HOME</a>
    <a href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And JS code:

```
(function() {
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])

    .config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/",{
                template: "Home!"
            })
            .when("/contact",{
                template: "Contact!"
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })

    .controller("MainCtrl", function() {
    });
})();
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: you have `app` not `MOPS`.

Comment: Typo! The problem still exists.

Comment: also you can use `ng-href` instead.

Comment: But that doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you have to setup rewrite rules.
You have no `/contacts` on your server, it should map to your handler.

For example, for Apache it looks like (`.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html
```